# Exchange transport rule to auto-CC a distribution group, when a message is sent from that distribution group

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have what is a bit of an odd business request - we have a distribution group, and when any email is sent on behalf of that group, it needs to CC itself. Since exchange mail flow rules don't seem to allow you to directly reference distribution groups, we originally had it set up like: if the sender is [distribution group] bcc a mailbox that just exists to forward emails back to the distribution group.
This works in the sense that any message sent from the distribution group will make it's way back to the group; although I'm now being asked to change this flow so that any message from [distribution group] will just add [distribution list] to the CC field of any email sent.

Is this possible with Exchange online? I saw some solutions online that would work assuming we managed our own SMTP server, but we don't so those won't work for me. Maybe some method of just directly altering the message headers through powershell, or something similar?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. I'm able to create a mail flow rule in Exchange Online that allows me to select a Distribution Group as the sender (the rule condition) and CC it to the same Distribution Group (the rule action).

Comment: Can you send a photo of that? Similar to Yuki Sun's answer I am unable to do that

Comment: @joeqwerty Could you share more details or post a screenshot so that we can learn how the rule is created?

Answer (score 0):

```
although I'm now being asked to change this flow so that any message from [distribution group] will just add [distribution list] to the CC field of any email sent.
```

Based on my knowledge and test, it's not feasible to add a distribution group to the CC field by mail flow rule. I tried it in my test tenant and the following error prompted, which indicated that adding a distribution list as a receipient is not supported:
[image]

So per current situation, I'd recommend keep using the old method, that is bcc a mailbox and have the mailbox autoforward emails back to the distribution group.